# Upload non-java files to Nexus/Artifactory

Tags: nexus, artifactory

I want to upload cobol files to Nexus. These cobol files can be equipped with groupId, artifactId, version. For packaging/type I would use `cobol`.

Is there any harm in doing this (these files are not zipped like jar,war,ear,zip)?

At the moment we are using Nexus 2.14, but I would like to use this method in the future also with Nexus 3.x or Artifactory.

The reason: Our developers often have to release wars/ears and cobol simultaneously and I would like to handle them in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Repository Managers are at their core somewhat like hard drives.  There's no harm in putting anything in them but there can be problems on usage, which is generally more the concern.  Without knowing the specific usage, it's really impossible to say.

NXRM3 does have a "raw" format which is intended for "everything else" use so not as to tangle with your actual repository formats.  Documentation here: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Raw+Repositories+and+Maven+Sites

That being said there are use cases where formats need to intermingle with things outside their norm and thus it is helpful to be stored side by side.  The default security of a NXRM repository prevents this but can be lowered to accept anything (temporarily or permanently).  See the "Strict Content Validation Type" field in a repository configuration.  This is at your own risk=)